# Is $y[n]=x[n]-x[n-1]$ invertible system?

Tags: signal-processing

Well, the title says everything.
I know I can find a z-transform, find $H(z)$ and then find a appropriate invert system and comment on that.
How do I explain it to a person who does not know z-transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not. Take two different constant functions say $x_1[n]$ and $x_2[n]$. Then their output is the same, zero. Hence the given system $y[n]$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a differentiator.  Explain that only the difference between successive input signals is output.

Show an integrator that would sum the differences that would restore the signal.

Comment: Does it restore the signal? Seems like it will be off by a constant.

Comment: Ah yes,  there is a constant at the start that is thrown out by the first operation.  So he may require a start at zero. Or an initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_1[n] = 1$ and $x_2[n] = 2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Both have output $y[n]=0 $. The system cannot be inverted: one  output cannot distinguish at least two different inputs.